# Ruby app: link_to 'delete' looking for GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, destroy

I realize this question has been asked many times, but I've tried all the solutions I can find, and have gotten nowhere.

In my view, I have

```
= link_to "Delete", evint_path(e), :method => :delete, data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}
```

where e is an instance of evint. I keep getting error messages declaring that I'm missing a GET method for evint:

```
No route matches [GET] "/evints/5"
```

This isn't even the case! When I rake routes, I have a GET route for evints.

I have jquery-rails in my Gemfile; I have "require jquery_ujs" in my application.js file. I have five other apps on the same system that work, so I don't think it's a system problem.

The html being generated by my code looks OK:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/evints/5" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
```

I've tried removing "//= require tree ." from my application.js file, but that didn't make any difference.

I'm also having trouble signing out of my app, as devise's destroy_session also isn't working!

Does anybody have any ideas? This is driving me crazy!

EDIT: Here are my routes:

```
                                                                             new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new                                                                                                             
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create                                                                                                          
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy                                                                                                         
user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create                                                                                                         
new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new                                                                                                            
edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit                                                                                                           
PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update                                                                                                         
PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update                                                                                                         
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           devise/registrations#cancel                                                                                                     
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#create                                                                                                     
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          devise/registrations#new                                                                                                            edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             devise/registrations#edit                                                                                                       
PATCH  /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update                                                                                                     
PUT    /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#update                                                                                                     
DELETE /users(.:format)                  devise/registrations#destroy                                                                                                    
user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create                                                                                                     
new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new                                                                                                        
GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show                                                                                                       
interests GET    /interests(.:format)              interests#index                                                                                                                 
POST   /interests(.:format)              interests#create                                                                                                                
new_interest GET    /interests/new(.:format)          interests#new                                                                                                                   
edit_interest GET    /interests/:id/edit(.:format)     interests#edit                                                                                                                  
interest GET    /interests/:id(.:format)          interests#show                                                                                                                  
PATCH  /interests/:id(.:format)          interests#update                                                                                                                
PUT    /interests/:id(.:format)          interests#update                                                                                                                
DELETE /interests/:id(.:format)          interests#destroy                                                                                                               
events GET    /events(.:format)                 events#index                                                                                                                    
POST    /events(.:format) events#create                                                                                                                   
new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)             events#new                        

edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)        events#edit                                                                                                                     
event GET    /events/:id(.:format)             events#show                                                                                                                     
PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)             events#update                                                                                                                   
PUT    /events/:id(.:format)             events#update                                                                                                                   
DELETE /events/:id(.:format)             events#destroy                                                                                                                  
images GET    /images(.:format)                 images#index                                                                                                                    
POST   /images(.:format)                 images#create                                                                                                                   
new_image GET    /images/new(.:format)             images#new                                                                                                                      
image GET    /images/:id(.:format)             images#show                                                                                                                     
DELETE /images/:id(.:format)             images#destroy                                                                                                                  
evints GET    /evints(.:format)                 evints#index                                                                                                                    
POST   /evints(.:format)                 evints#create                                                                                                                   
new_evint GET    /evints/new(.:format)             evints#new                                                                                                                      
evint DELETE /evints/:id(.:format)             evints#destroy                                                                                                                  
projects GET    /projects(.:format)               projects#index                                                                                                                  
POST   /projects(.:format)               projects#create                                                                                                                 
new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)           projects#new                                                                                                                    
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)      projects#edit                                                                                                                   
project PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)           projects#update                                                                                                                 
PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)           projects#update                                                                                                                 
projectimages GET    /projectimages(.:format)          projectimages#index                                                                                                                 
POST   /projectimages(.:format)          projectimages#create                                                                                                            
new_projectimage GET    /projectimages/new(.:format)      projectimages#new                                                                                                               
projectimage GET    /projectimages/:id(.:format)      projectimages#show                                                                                                              
DELETE /projectimages/:id(.:format)      projectimages#destroy                                                                                                           
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)          welcome#index                                                                                                                   
root GET    /                                 welcome#index                                                                                                                   
welcome_readpdf GET    /welcome/readpdf(.:format)        welcome#readpdf
```

Comment: please show output of 'rake routes'

Comment: Wow, that is weird.  other than mixing hash rockets and new style hashes, the link looks good.  Do you have any JavaScript errors on the page?

Comment: No JavaScript errors that I'm aware of . . .

Comment: If you're using chrome, in the inspector go to the network tab, and make sure that you're app is loading jquery_ujs. If it is, it will appear as its own line in the network tab.

Comment: I don't see jquery_ujs in the network tab. Why would that happen?

Comment: If its in your application.js file, make sure that there are no spaces before all of the require statements. A commented out line is fine, but any totally blank line will cause whatever is after it to not be included.

Comment: The easiest thing to do is put the require statements at the very top of your file.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I checked to make sure there were no spaces *and* moved them to the top of the file, and nothing's changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72800/discussion-between-xcskier56-and-ellen-w).

Comment: Did you restart your server? Try it